# Can I use Sass in my production environment with Ruby only installed on my development environment?

Tags: ruby, sass

Sass needs Ruby to work. I can install Ruby in my development environment. Nonetheless, I cannot do it in some production environments (hostings).

The reason I think it might work is because the `.css` files are created every time I run the sass command in my local environment, so once I deploy (push) my website to my server, it has all the `.css` files already transcribed.

Am I wrong? Do I still need to run the sass command in my server?

Comment: What kind of "app" is that?

Comment: A website, a typical html, css, js website.

Comment: Try it without uploading the Sass files and find out?

Comment: @jdjuan well, HTML, CSS and JavaScript don't require Ruby ;-)

Comment: @Stefan, I know but Sass does. So given the answer of **Standelaune** I would only require Ruby on my local environment, and then I won't need it in my server since the .css files were already created. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Once the SCSS files are compiled into CSS, you dont need ruby anymore and can use the CSS files as is.